# Static property nonstatic field

Tags: vb.net

I was just wondering if it is good style to use Static property for a nonstatic field. 
In my case, this seems to be the only way that I could correctly get the information.
Thanks.

Nevermind guys, I realized I made a really stupid error. But thanks anyways :DD

Comment: For clarity can you show you code?

Comment: Well... If you try it Visual Studio gives an error: Properties cannot be declared 'Static'. I'd say no, since it's impossible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you provide more details on why you want to do this?